# Oracle JPEG compression - file sizes

Tags: image, oracle, image-compression

We have an unsupported Oracle application running 9i as the database server and 10g on the application server.

As part of the application we are able to load and save photos (jpeg) within the database.  We have started using the photos for different purposes and I have noticed that there is a huge difference in file size where comparing the preload file with the image when exported.  Can anyone explain why this is happening.

As an example when we load a 10mb file, the photo is only just over 1mb when extracted.  There is on average an 84% decrease in the exported file size over the original photo.  The image dimensions are still the same size as is the dpi.  Any ideas why the exported images are significantly smaller then the images loaded to the database.

Thanks,

Comment: How are the images stored?  As BLOBs, an Oracle media type like ORDImage, or something else?

Comment: Hi Jon, the data type of the field is BLOB.

Comment: In that case you'll need to give more information about how the file is stored and retrieved.  The database would not normally do any transformations to a BLOB, it would just store whatever 1s and 0s were passed in.